# Intellij Idea svn configuration

Tags: svn, configuration, intellij-idea

I want to configure two svn repositories and checkout from them via Intelij idea cvs/svn plugin. I have configured network templates via Version Control/Svn/EditNetworkOptions dialog.
One template for each svn repository 0 including  URL Pattern field and Server (without port - check url via browser - it works)
all I got when trying add new repository location is
svn: E175002: connection refused by the server
Previously configured locations works fine.
Please suggest.

Comment: Did you try to checkout externally and then just set up mappings in `Settings` | `Version Control`? IDEA uses metadata from `.svn` directories to find the correct remote repository and you normally don't need to set up any additional networking options.